# Check if database is available before job in spring batch

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

My question is how to check if the database is available before starting a job in Spring batch.

I tried to create a new class which implements `JobExecutionListener`, and call a method into `beforeJob`. The problem is how to do this test, because the database configuration is in `database-context.xml`?

database-context.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB_3" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

For example, when I put `myDB_4` (and `myDB_4` doesn't exist), I get the following error:

```
Error while extracting database product name - falling back to empty error codes
org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'myDB_4'
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:293)
```

Now how to catch this error and check if this database is available in my method created in `beforeJob`?

Comment: Could you try to connect to the database and handle Exception in this method, write the flag and check it in actual batch?